# gcc: how to save all used register on function entry

Tags: gcc, interrupt, riscv

This is regarding gcc used for RISC-V, but it probably also applies to other targets.

If I declare a function as ISR using `__attribute__((interrupt))`, gcc automatically saves and restores all used registers by the ISR. GCC will also generate a return-from-interrupt instruction (`mret`) at the end of the function instead of a regular function return (`ret`).

Is it possible to instruct gcc to save all used registers just like with an ISR, but instead of generating an mret instruction it should generate a regular ret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin support for this in GCC. Typically this is resolved by making a small trampoline stub which saves all caller-saved registers and then calls the real function normally.

Or, if the only needed change is replacing `mret` with `ret`, you could simply postprocess generated assembly code:

```
$ gcc file.c -S -o file.s
$ sed -i -e 's/\bmret\b/ret/'
```

Comment: I would like to save only the registers that are actually used in the function. Adding a trampoline stub will have to save all caller-saved registers because it doesn't know which registers the function is actually modifying.

Comment: @dsula "save only the registers that are actually used in the function" - this is possible only if the function is leaf i.e. does not call other functions (otherwise all caller-saved registers have to be saved). And yes, that's the price you'll have to pay.